# How to call a stored procedure in using repository pattern without passing procedure name as a string

Tags: c#, sql, repository-pattern

I’ve got stack in one problem. I use a generic repository and try to call a stored procedure with it. The only way I know is to call

```
DataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
```

Or

```
DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql, parameters);
```

passing a procedure name as a string. But I do already have the procedure in my DBContext. Is there really no way to avoid passing procedure name as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific problem you have with the string type, or are you referring to "magic strings" as in a constant that is defined in the repo?  Would you be more comfortable passing the string names in via the constructor as configured values and then letting the DI container provide them?

Another option, you could define an extension method to the Database object that has the string and wraps ExecuteSqlCommand or SqlQuery and name it the same as your stored procedure so it would look like `DataContext.Database.MyStoredProcedure(paramaters)`, that way your repository is ignorant of this implementation detail.

That being said, when I use a repository pattern one of the goals of the repository is to hide the implementation details of persistence,  I personally see no problem in just using a string, since anything that invokes the repository is none the wiser.

Comment: Well of course I could use enums to store procedure names, but as soon as I already have a procedure in DBContext I thought there shall be some possibility to use it analogic to DbSet<Entity>.. I find the way passing strings kind of unclean for I prefer to get compile errors after I change smth. in the Model instead of getting “masked” errors that I have to find out with unit tests. But actually that is only a question of my preferences. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Sure you could use enums, but if somebody changes the schema and renames the sproc it's still a runtime error.

Perhaps the underlying issue is the generic repository?  I usually prefer a repository per aggregate, and in doing so I would have no problem having specifics for a given model in the repository.  I could see how if you're using a generic repository it could end up being a "god class" with a million stored procedures in it.

Comment: I think you are right… maybe I shall really change my repository concept.